# Lightning App Builder - Source Code For Built-In Templates?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-app-builder, page-template

When editing a page in the Lightning App Builder, we can edit the layout template:

[image]

I want to make my own custom template based on one of the Standard, out-of-box templates - can I view the source of those somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The source code for the standard templates is not public. You can inspect elements on the browser but it is hard to decipher.

Creating your own [templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm) is simpler with `lightning-layout`. There are a couple of [examples](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc) in the sample app Easy Spaces.

[3:9 layout](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc/tree/develop/es-base-styles/main/default/aura/AppPage_3_9)

[4:8 layout](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc/tree/develop/es-base-styles/main/default/aura/AppPage_4_8)

A sample component for 4:8 will be as below

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:appHomeTemplate" description="App Home template, with 2 columns in 4:8 ratio."
access="global">
<aura:attribute name="leftColumn" type="Aura.Component[]" access="global" />
<aura:attribute
    name="rightColumn"
    type="Aura.Component[]"
    access="global"
/>
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem
            aura:id="leftColumn"
            size="4"
            class="left expanded"
        >
            {!v.leftColumn}
        </lightning:layoutItem>

        <lightning:layoutItem aura:id="rightColumn" size="8" class="right">
            {!v.rightColumn}
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: LWC components became open-source recently - any plan to make Aura components open source?

Comment: @jbyrd No those won't go open source ever since the future is all LWC! At some point LWC will be available for every interface on Salesforce platform

Comment: Thanks - yeah I keep hearing that, but unfortunately the codebase on this project is mostly Aura. LWC being the future, does that also mean the lightning app builder is sort of getting deprecated, too, at some point?

Comment: No lightning app builder won’t be deprecated but it will be LWR based!

Comment: So now my question is (and perhaps this is better suited for a separate question or a discussion): I have created simple custom templates like with 3 columns, I even made left and right columns collapsible, but **How do I create a template like the "Pinned Header and Left Sidebar"** where the description is "Full-width header and two sidebars with fixed proportional widths. In Lightning console apps, the header and left sidebar stay pinned for subtabs." Specifically that last part **"the header and left sidebar stay pinned for subtabs"**

Comment: Ok created a new question for it: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/344516/89720