# How To Create a Pinned Region in Custom Page Template

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, template, page-template

In a Lightning App, I've already created a custom page template successfully - relatively straightforward.

Now I need to create a custom page template that includes a pinned region, like in some of the Standard tempates - for example, the `Pinned Header and Left Sidebar (2 regions)`:

[image]

You can see when I hover over the pinned region, it describes the behavior: "A pinned region remains displayed when you're viewing subtabs in a Lightning console app. For example, if you add a Related Record component here, it displays even when you're viewing a subtab."

**How do I create a pinned region in my own custom page template?**

Comment: This seems to be related to this idea : https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003eCzQAI